# deploy project Node.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hosting

When I start the site on the hosting I get the error

'h12 Request timeout'.[heroku logs]

[image]

I do everything according to the instructions on the official website. What could be the problem?

[my project on github](https://github.com/vitarunaeva/vlgplace.git)

Comment: This might be hard to diagnose without more info. This might help thought: https://help.heroku.com/AXOSFIXN/why-am-i-getting-h12-request-timeout-errors-in-nodejs

Comment: fixed image and grammer

Comment: what images and grammars to fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow all deploy instruction properly it won't give any error, please check this [Deployment process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)

> Note: Make sure that you must have access to deploy applications.

Comment: I carefully followed this instruction. Access is available, the  program "hello world" has been successfully deployed, but my project doesn't work out

Comment: then restart server  `heroku restart --app <your app name>` and then `heroku logs -t --app <your app name>` to verify what exactly happening.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the logs you provided, your server application was unable to connect to the MongoDB database. It was unable then to finish the `Photo.find()` query, that you have under the `'/'` path in your router and probably the operation finished with error. Please keep in mind, that if any Mongoose operation finished with error, you need to handle it. If you don't, the request will finished with timeout (like in your case), because server will not return anything to the client, that made the request to server.

Edit:
I also went deeper into your code and discovered, that you are trying to connect with database, which is on `localhost`. The DB probably does not exist on the same Heroku server, where you are deploying your app, so you need to fix the DB URI.